# Execute task after n hours after function being called

Tags: node.js

I have a function that receives a URL and stores it in the database. I would like to execute a validation of that URL after 24 hours of that function being called.

This function may be called by multiple users, and so the following behavior would ensue:

`User A submits URL at 22:00 of the 25th - URL is validated at 22:00 of the 26th`

`User B submits URL at 23:00 of the 25th - URL is validated at 23:00 of the 26th`

Is there some kind of queuing system/scheduler in Node that I can use to achieve this? Keep in mind that I wouldn't like to use a cronjob-like functionality, as it provides a fixed spacing in time regardless of the time of submission.

Comment: Create cron task that will be executed every hour. In the task check how many links should be validated as time windows is close to 24 hours.

Comment: Yes, and  maintain created_at timestamp to check that

Comment: This means I would have to compromise processing posts to the exact minute, unless I run a cron every minute, right? (e.g. A user posts at 22:01, it will only be processed at 23:00 next day)

Comment: @ManuelReis I don't understand why you don't want to use a cron job, that's exactly what you need... When the function gets called, create a cron job for exactly 24 hours later (every day at the exact time), when that cron job executes, stop or destroy the cron. https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron is good.

Comment: @AllTheTime Yes, that makes sense. Just one quick question: Won't the approach of creating/destroying crons on demand degrade performance? A cron launching a node process for every request a user makes (could be thousands or more) does not seem very efficient. (unless a new cron process is not created for every request...)